# Get img tag details using preg_replace [PHP]

Tags: php, html, regex

This is my content:

```
<p><img src="http://localhost/contents/uploads/2017/11/1.jpg" width="215" height="1515"></p>
```

This is my PHP code:

```
function convert_the_content($content){
    $content = preg_replace('/<p><img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', "<p class=\"uploaded-img\"><img class=\"lazy-load\" data-src=\"$1\" /></p>", $content);
    return $content;
}
```

I using my code to add a class for `<p>` tag and `<img>` tag and to convert `src=""` to `data-src=""`.

The problem that my code has removed the width and the height attr from `<img>` tag, So my question is how can i change my code to work and getting this details with it too?

**NOTE: My content may have many of `<img>` and `<p>` tags.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have this very exact HTML snippet, you can do it simpler by just doing

```
$html = <<< HTML
<p><img src="http://localhost/contents/uploads/2017/11/1.jpg" width="215" height="1515"></p>
HTML;

$html = str_replace('<p>', '<p class="foo">', $html);
$html = str_replace(' src=', ' data-src=', $html);
echo $html;
```

This will output

```
<p class="foo"><img data-src="http://localhost/contents/uploads/2017/11/1.jpg" width="215" height="1515"></p>
```

If you are trying to convert arbitrary HTML, [consider using a DOM Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php/3577662#3577662) instead:

```
<?php
$html = <<< HTML
<html>
  <body>
    <p><img src="http://localhost/contents/uploads/2017/11/1.jpg" width="215" height="1515"></p>
    <p><img width="215" height="1515" src="http://localhost/contents/uploads/2017/11/1.png"></p>
      <p   ><img
        class="blah"
            height="1515" 
            width="215"
       src="http://localhost/contents/uploads/2017/11/1.png"

       >
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//p[img]') as $paragraphWithImage) {
    $paragraphWithImage->setAttribute('class', 'foo');
    foreach ($paragraphWithImage->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image) {
        $image->setAttribute('class', trim('bar ' . $image->getAttribute('class')));
        $image->setAttribute('data-src', $image->getAttribute('src'));
        $image->removeAttribute('src');
    }
};

echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);
```

**Output:**

```
<html><body>
    <p class="foo"><img width="215" height="1515" class="bar" data-src="http://localhost/contents/uploads/2017/11/1.jpg"></p>
    <p class="foo"><img width="215" height="1515" class="bar" data-src="http://localhost/contents/uploads/2017/11/1.png"></p>
      <p class="foo"><img class="bar blah" height="1515" width="215" data-src="http://localhost/contents/uploads/2017/11/1.png"></p>
  </body></html>
```

Comment: No, it's not an exact HTML because that I want to use preg_replace, It's not possible to do what I need using preg_replace?

Comment: it is possible but very difficult to write reliable patterns for arbitrary html. dom parsers are simpler

Comment: @Gordon Unfortunately, I tried to argue OP to use DomDocument some questions back but without result :(

Comment: @Gordon Thank you, But i think something wrong the code is working and add a class for <p> tag, yes but it's not changing anything for images it does not add a class for <img> tag and not change src= to data-src=

Comment: @sadadadadasdad sorry. fixed.